# Program type already present: net.sf.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$BeanCopierKey while building with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, compiler-errors, android-studio-3.0, cglib

I'm a noob in the android automation and I do my first steps (in windows). I have my first program in android studio 3.1 and Appium server. when I try to run the program I get:

```
Program type already present: net.sf.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$BeanCopierKey
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: net.sf.cglib.beans.BeanCopier$BeanCopierKey, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I've tried to delete the cglib jar from the gradle external libraries but error persist.
from "gradlew dependencies" command (windows) I didnt see any cglib dependencies

I'm stuck on this for more than a week. any help will be very much appreciated

below are my **build.gradle** and **gradle.properties** files

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.shayg.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"



    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation ('com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2')
            {exclude group: "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2"
                exclude group:"net.sf.cglib.beans"}
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1')
            {exclude group: "com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0"
                exclude group:"net.sf.cglib.beans"}
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    implementation ('io.appium:java-client:4.0.0')
            {exclude group:"org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53.0"
                exclude group:"com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1"
                exclude group:"org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1"
                exclude group:"commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9"
                exclude group:"commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1"
                exclude group:"commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1"
                exclude group:"net.sf.cglib.beans"
            }
    implementation ('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53.1')
            {exclude group:"com.google.code.gson"
                exclude group:"net.sf.cglib.beans"}

}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.parallel=true 
enableD8="false"
```